# How do I keep a child controller from inheriting a parent controller's scope in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

If I have a nested controller in AngularJS (one controller inherits from another), how do I keep the child controller from having access to the parent controller's scope? This was asked as an interview question to me.

Comment: Why would you want to avoid inheritance if you make a conscious choice to use inheritance?

Comment: maxbe you are looking for a feature in angular called [isolating scope](http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-sticky-notes-pt-2-isolated-scope/). see also  [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) for further information

Comment: Actually this question was asked during my Interview with one of the MNC company. So wanted to know if is their anyway for it.

Comment: using service or factory or isolate scope we can avoid inheritance.

Comment: If its not in directive as Isolated scope is part of directive. Then how can we avoid ?

Comment: I agree isolating scope is a feature related to directives. There are two possibilities. 1) The child controller should be refactored as a directive. 2) This is something nobody want's to do ;-)

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to isolate controller's scope:

> The following create new scopes, and inherit prototypically: ng-repeat, ng-include, ng-switch, ng-view, **ng-controller**, directive with scope: true, directive with transclude: true. [doc](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes#angular-scope-inheritance)

To create an isolated scope, you should use directive instead of controller. Be sure that you defined a *scope* property in your directive declaration. [doc](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes#directives)

Answer (score 2):

With just using ng-controller you cannot isolate the scope, however you can isolate the methods on the controller by returning than on the controller and not placing them on the scope.

```
.controller('myCtrl', function() {
    return {
        doStuff: function() {
        }
    }
})
```

A child controller would not have access to the `doStuff` function. The only way to use it would be using the `controller as`

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl as parentCtrl">
    <button ng-click="parentCtrl.doStuff()"/>
</div>
```